# Can I get longer contigs by changing MEGAHIT settings?

Tags: assembly, metagenome

My current settings are `megahit -r input.fq --num-cpu-threads 32 --min-contig-len 300 --presets meta-large -o output`. I picked the 'presets meta-large' because I am dealing with a quite large and diverse metagenome out of which I only need some genes.

I've got a contig of interest ~19kb, with a depth of 16. Could I make this contig larger with more relaxed settings? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `--k-step 10` and `--kmin-1pass` for low-coverage datasets.